# A variant triangle inequality

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $f,g \in L^p$ with $ 0 < p \le 1$. Let $||f|| = (\int |f|^p)^{1/p}$ be the usual $L_p $ norm of $f$. How to establish $|| f + g||^p \le ||f||^p + ||g||^p$? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** You only need to show $(u+v)^p\le u^p+v^p$ for $u,v>0$.

**More hint:** Let $x=v/u$ and divide the above by $u^p$. Now you only have to show $(1+x)^p\le 1+x^p$ for $x>0$. This is a calculus problem.

Comment: Yes, I get this point. Then I get stuck on it...

Comment: Hint 2: integrate. Hint 3: you're done.

Comment: @DanielFischer But $p<1$.

Comment: Duh. Overlooked that. Thought $p\geqslant 1$ because of the $\left(\int \lvert f\rvert^p\right)^{1/p}$, as for $p < 1$, I am used to not taking the $p$-th root.

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes, the notation used in this problem sucks.